# orientationchange JQM - incorrect values for Android

Tags: android, html, web-applications, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQM and for orientation change i use:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', handleOrientationChange);

function handleOrientationChange() {
       var viewportWidth = 0;
           var viewportHeight = 0;

           // calculate map height and width
           if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
               viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
               viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
           } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
               viewportWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
               viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
           } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
               viewportWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
               viewportHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
}
```

In Android, when calling the handle function i get the dimensions before the orientation has changed and not after. In IPhone it works OK.
I need to add a small delay of 0.5/1 second...

Does anybody knows the reason for that or have a better solution?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the `setTimeout` idea successfully. Just make sure to only set one timeout at a time:

```
var oc_timer;
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function () {
    clearTimeout(oc_timer);
    oc_timer = setTimeout(handleOrientationChange, 500);
});
```

I believe the problem is that the `orientationchange` event gets triggered too fast on Android devices and the viewport dimensions have yet to be updated when the event fires. I've tried binding to the `resize` event but it also needed a timeout.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But why would i need to use a timeout? In the IPhone it works without waiting for 500 mS.
BTW I have Samsung Galaxy S2 and 500mS wasn't enough. I tested it on Galaxy S1 and it was enough. For S2 1 second delay did the trick but this looks very ugly to use.